# Vuforia video playback, video is black

Tags: video, unity-game-engine, arm, augmented-reality, vuforia

The issue is like the below picture,
[image]

and this is my project setting. Are there some wrong settings?

[image]

Do you know what cause this issue, and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Video playback version must be same as Vuforia version.
Furthermore if you have sound maybe your video codec need to be changed.

Comment: video is streamed, I use version 5.5.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer.

Turn the **multi threading** off

[image: multi threaded rendering unity 5.6]

Comment: I have the same problem, but my Unity version is different (5.6.1), and the setting isn't available anymore. Any idea ?

Comment: I have a look at 5.6.0 (the version I installed now), there is the option `mutithreaded rendering`, try to turn it off.

Comment: Yes, the option exists in Android building settings, but not for iOS building settings, and my problem is that black screen issues happens on iOS devices :-/

Comment: ok, i do not have an ios device now, I do not think I can help. maybe you can ask a new question or ask on vuforia forum?